# Telerik-Grid: Enable skin classnames in addition to HeaderStyle-CssClass

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, css

I'm using telerik ASP.Net Ajax grid component, and I'm facing a problem.

If I'm adding *HeaderStyle-CssClass="SomeClassName"* to the telerik:GridBoundColumn, telerik won't add the Sorted classname on sorting the grid.

I.e. if I added a custom classname using HeaderStyle-CssClass, on sorting the column, the class name stays, and than I loose functionality of the grid. Than my sorted TH doesn't get the sorted BG Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the HeaderStyle-CssClass for one of these controls, you have to make sure you include it's original class as well. It difficult to say for sure if something is over-writing your th's, but [this post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/setting-columns-headerstyle-cssclass-prevents-default-css-classes-from-rendering-rgheader-rgsorted.aspx) leads me to think it could be a possibility. Give it a try, telerik controls look awesome, but they can be tempermental when you play with them.

Comment: Sorry for seeing your comment only now. When I'll get back to the project, I'll give it a try.